# Powershell script scheduled task output to log file

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have Powershell script with some `Write-Host` but I want to use it as scheduled task.

I added it as scheduled task with this:

```
$action  = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "$pshome\powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden" -Argument "-File $FilePath"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).Date -RepetitionInterval $repeat
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $Name -Trigger $trigger -RunLevel Highest -Action $action
```

Can I make it write to log file? Is it possible to make it write to file at the same location as the Powershell script?

Comment: yes, either use `Out-File` cmdlet, or you can schedule the script to redirect output to file `.\script.ps1 > scriptOut.log` You can also do both stout and sterr. `.\script.ps1 > script_out.log 2>&1`

Comment: Did you try changing the `Write-Host` statements to `Out-File` or `Add-Content`?  The location of the current script can be obtained from the `$PsScriptRoot` variable.

Comment: Both suggestions end up with showing "How do you want to open this file" modal

Comment: @Gerhard I've used this when in the Powershell console. In the scheduled task it is executed with `-WindowStyle Hidden`. Can this cause the strange behavior?

Comment: Well, That was just an example. I would suggest you use [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7) cmdlet rather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 problems with the script and the 1st was my **main** problem:

1. if it is not signed default behavior is to be sckipped by the Task Scheduler (or at least I didn't saw an error in the Event Viewer).
2. I had to use Write-Output

---

Check if the script is signed with [Get-AuthenticodeSignature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-authenticodesignature). Here you are going to receive [SignatureStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.signaturestatus) as string:

```
$isSigned = Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath $FilePath | select -ExpandProperty Status
```

If it is not signed, you can enable the execution of it by adding `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` like it is described in this [spiceworks how-to](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler). Do this for your own scripts, because of security !

---

For the writing part I used [Write-Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Output) and [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file):

```
(
   ...
   Write-Output "some text here"
   ...
) | Out-File -FilePath "C:\somepath\log.log
```