# How to Schedule Powershell JOB to run every 5 minutes

Tags: powershell

I am trying to schedule Powershell job to run my logging script every 5 minutes. The reason I don't use Windows Task Scheduler is I want it to run in background without Powershell window poping up. I checked Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psscheduledjob/?view=powershell-5.1) and tried following commands:

```
#path 
$path = "C:\path\to\Loggingscript.ps1"

#JOB Trigger
$jobtrigger = New-JobTrigger -Once -At "24/11/2020 15:35:00" -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5) -RepeatIndefinitely

#JOB Option 
$joboption = New-ScheduledJobOption -RunElevated

#JOB
Register-ScheduledJob -Name "Logging" -FilePath $path -ScheduledJobOption $joboption -Trigger $jobtrigger
```

Job was created:

```
Id         Name            JobTriggers     Command                                  Enabled
--         ----            -----------     -------                                  -------
1          Logging         1               C:\path\to\Loggingscript...               True
```

However the Job did not run. I know that, because my log file was not created. (The Script I run is working well). I wanted to check if there is powershell command for powershell scheduled jobs history but I did not find anything.

So I checked my Time string. **"24/11/2020 15:35:00"** This one is ok, because if I flip month and day then I get error.

So what am I doing wrong?

**Edit 26.11.2020**

So I did few recomended things. Firstly i made fairly simple script I will run with Powershell Jobs. (My Original Script is over 900 lines long and contains few work related data which i can not share.) My script contains:

```
$Time = Get-Date
Write-output    "Test at $Time" | Out-File -width 1000 C:\Test\Logfile.log
```

Then I executed the commands as before now with different script.

```
$path = "C:\Test\testLogging.ps1"

$jobtrigger = New-JobTrigger -Once -At "26/11/2020 08:28:00" -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5) -RepeatIndefinitely

$joboption = New-ScheduledJobOption -RunElevated

Register-ScheduledJob -Name "Test" -FilePath $path -ScheduledJobOption $joboption -Trigger $jobtrigger
```

I checked Task Scheduler as advised. Both Powershell Jobs (My original and Test) are listed but no record in Run History. (History is activated) Manualy Starting the task also does not work.

As before I also got in Powershell confirmation after creation.

```
Id         Name            JobTriggers     Command                                  Enabled
--         ----            -----------     -------                                  -------
1          Test            1               C:\Test\testLogging.ps1                  True
```

The path is in this case real. I can run the script manually in Powershell with admin rights with this command:

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Test\testLogging.ps1
```

With this said I am actually wondering whether the Powershell Jobs tool is blocked by execution policy.

So I did this:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Lernen Sie das neue plattformübergreifende PowerShell kennen – https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ExecutionPolicy
Unrestricted
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I still can not successfully run Powershell Job.

Comment: Your joboption has an unknown parameter for New-ScheduledJobOption.  Maybe you meant -RunElevated

Comment: This was copy paste issue, I will edit the post.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the script you are scheduling. For testing, write the file to an absolute path, edit permissions to allow everyone r/w access to that path. Have a look in task scheduler if the scheduled job has actually run (Microsoft/Windows/PowerShell/ScheduledJobs). In your scheduled script, make sure to check for each possible error. On error, call `Exit 1`, which you will see as the task result in task scheduler.

Comment: you need to get the output of the job by using `Receive-Job` where you can actually check the output is coming or not. Sometimes, the job might run but the script or function can end up in some issues... In that case also, you job execution is fine and successful.

Comment: I created a simple Script for test purposes and I ran into same issue. I updated my post. Now it should not be problem to replicate my issue.

Comment: I had similar problem. Either sign the script or add `bypass`. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936204/powershell-script-scheduled-task-output-to-log-file